# Get the post feed of a public facebook page

Tags: swift, facebook

I'm working on an app and I need to pull in the public posts from the page of a business. I do not want users to login or send any information back to Facebook, I just need the posts so they can be shown in a read-only format.

I've looked around and from what I've read, Facebook offers ways to authenticate your connection to the API, but for security reasons you shouldn't make the calls directly from your app. I've seen something called a client token mentioned, that is assumed to be insecure, but I can't find much mention of it outside of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens. It says it can be found in the app dashboard, but I have not been able to find it.

How do you make a call to get the posts of a public facebook page from an iOS app?

Comment: _“How do you make a call to get the posts of a public facebook page from an iOS app?”_ - you either make users log in, so that you can use their token - or you don’t do it client-side at all, but put it on a server somewhere, where you can use your app access token or a page access token, and then have your iOS app get the data from there.

Comment: @CBroe in the page I linked to it says that the clinical token is specifically for embedding "into native mobile binaries or desktop apps to identify your app". I know that a way I can do it is by using a server, but for cost reasons that is not an option with this app. Similarly, no other part of the app needs the user to login to Facebook and the page in question is publicly available, so it seems cumbersome to have users login to their accounts. It also prevents users who don't have Facebook from making full use of the app (despite being able to see the page on Facebook without logging in).

Comment: Read on: _“The client token is used to access app-level APIs, but only a very limited subset. The client token is found in your app's dashboard. Since the client token is used rarely, we won't talk about it in this document. Instead it's covered in any API documentation that uses the client token.”_ - I don’t know what specifically you _can_ use it for - but it definitively doesn’t work for requesting a page’s feed via API. It simply is not a valid Graph API access token.

Comment: I guess that was my disconnect. When working with the Facebook tool for making web calls, it allowed the calling of public information without any special permissions - just a token. I had read that section, but didn't interpret app-level APIs as not including a page's publicly available feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding something that wasn't quite what I was looking for, but still got the job done: [Facebook Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin)

It lets you embed the publicly available feed of a Facebook page into a web page. If you want to use it in an app you can host the web page that has the feed code in it and then load it into a web view in the app.

[image]

Comment: Facebook page plugin works, if you want to somewhat "duplicate" experiencing fb in a web browser. But, 1. what if you want the text of each (public) post, e.g. to reformat or to send by other medium? and 2. you need the pageid; do you know how to browse (in code) for pages to get their id? e.g. for a user to choose.

Comment: @PabloH We wanted to be able to show the posts from the Facebook feed, but format it ourselves. We made the plugin full screen in the app, so it simulates the experience as best as we could without forcing the users to login. I think for anything more detailed you’d have to be calling Facebook’s API, with all the hurdles that that entails.